# Parsing JSON Android ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, json

I apologize if the title of my question is a bit misleading.

I created a POJO to hold CholesterolInformation about a user (HDL, LDL, Triglycerides, units, etc...). I now want to use my JSONObject to create an ArrayList so that I can generate some data points.

My JSONObject contains the following:

```
{
"cholesterol": [
    {
        "date": "2014-01-01",
        "hdl": "56464.0",
        "ldl": "46494.0",
        "triGlycaride": "0.0",
        "uid": "email@email.com",
        "unit": "mg"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-01-01",
        "hdl": "5.0",
        "ldl": "5.0",
        "triGlycaride": "0.0",
        "uid": "email@email.com",
        "unit": "mg"
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-01-01",
        "hdl": "6.0",
        "ldl": "6.0",
        "triGlycaride": "0.0",
        "uid": "email@email.com",
        "unit": "mg"
    }
]
}
```

My question is, how would one go about iterating through this JSON Object? I would like to maybe use a for each, and create a new object to add to the ArrayList in each iteration... Do you have any advice or suggestions?
**Note**: I have never used the JSONObject before, and thus am not too familiar with its usage.

**EDIT:** Thanks everybody, that was exactly what I was looking for. I need to get more familiar with JSON manipulation. And I will look into GSON as well!

Comment: If you want to avoid the iteration you can check [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Gson-Users) to map your JSON to your POJO. Check this [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create an ArrayList of your POJO? I assume you have getters and setters inside your POJO class. Initialize an ArrayList somewhere near the top like this

```
private ArrayList<CholesterolInformation> mCholesterol;
```

Now, parse through your json like this

```
JSONobject data = new JSONObject(jsonStringData);
JSONArray cholesterol = data.getJSONArray("cholesterol");
for(int i = 0; i < cholesterol.length; i++)
{
    JSONObject object = cholesterol.getJSONObject(i);
    // Create a new object of your POJO class
    CholesterolInformation ci = new CholesterolInformation();
    // Get value from JSON
    String date = object.getString("date");
    // Set value to your object using your setter method
    ci.setDate(date);
    String hdl = object.getString("hdl");
    ci.setHdl(hdl);
    .....
    .....
    // Finally, add the object to your arraylist
    mCholesterol.add(ci);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as suggested by Eric as you already created POJO.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<POJO>>() {}.getType();
List<POJO> mList = gson.fromJson(your_json_string_here, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's time to learn some JSON manipulation:

```
JSONArray array = yourJsonObject.optJSONArray("cholesterol");
if (array != null) {
    for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.optJSONObject(i);
        if (object != null) {
            // this is where you manipulate all the date, hdl, ldl...etc
        }
    }
}
```

you also should check for null before accessing the json